# Sequences of characters in java

Tags: java, regex

I was a exercise to do . "Sequences of characters - passwords, which from left to right consists of 3 consecutive digits, 4 letters (the English alphabet) consecutive, and one or more characters from the set {*, ^,%, #, ~,!, &, |, @, $}." I do it , but i isnt work :/

```
public class regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "[\\d]{3}[a-aZ-Z]{4}[,@!%]+";
        String txt = "394aZbr@";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);

        while(m.find()){
            String s = m.group();
            System.out.println("pass : " + s);
        }
```

Result of my exrcise :

```
pass: 493ahTz@
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: The question isn't clear. What do you want the program to do ?

Comment: Change `[a-aZ-Z]{4}` to `[a-zA-Z]{4}`...

Comment: @Cylian: I think you mean it should be changed to `[a-zA-Z]{4}`

Comment: thx , i must change [a-aZ-Z]{4} to [a-zA-Z]{4} . its work

Answer (score 0):

`[\\d]{3}[a-aZ-Z]{4}[,@!%]+`

1. Do not use `[]` if you are only using one `\d`, you can use `{3}` with `\d` directly.
2. `[a-aZ-Z]` that is exactly the same as `[aZ]`, you must use `[a-zA-Z]`
3. The last part seems good but you may want to add all the chars that you mentioned before.

Result: `\\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{4}[,@!%]+`

Comment: Another problem is that some character from the special set is missing in the character class.